# Any Examples for inserting values in Webtable columns using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I have infragistics web table where i am able to get the count but not to insert the values. please provide some examples on this.

WebElement Webtable=driver.findElement(By.id("x:1855522105.5:mkr:dataTbl.hdn")); // Replace TableID with Actual Table ID or Xpath
    List TotalRowCount=Webtable.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='x:1855522105.5:mkr:dataTbl.hdn']/tbody/tr"));

```
System.out.println("No. of Rows in the WebTable: "+TotalRowCount.size());
// Now we will Iterate the Table and print the Values   
int RowIndex=1;
for(WebElement rowElement:TotalRowCount)
{
      List<WebElement> TotalColumnCount=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
      int ColumnIndex=1;
      for(WebElement colElement:TotalColumnCount)
      {
           System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex+" Column "+ColumnIndex+" Data "+colElement.getText());
           ColumnIndex=ColumnIndex+1;
       }
      RowIndex=RowIndex+1;
 }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by inserting values? Are they editable fields? Of what kind? Do you have any html examples?

Comment: YES. fields are editable. and web-table is getting generated by third party tool (infragistics)

Comment: Give a simplified html example please :)

Comment: <tr id="x:1855522105.18:adr:0:tag:" tag="" adr="0" type="row">
<th class="ig_Office2007BlueHeader igg_Office2007BlueRowSelector igg_ItemRowSelectorClass " adr="0" type="selector"> </th>
<td id="x:1855522105.25:val:false" class="igede12b8d" style="width:50px;">
<img id="x:1855522105.24:chkState:0" title="Unchecked" alt="Unchecked" src="../App_Themes/Office2007Blue/images/ig_checkbox_off.gif">
</td>
<td class="ig2d2816fe" style="width: 40px;" idx="1" adr="1" type="cell" wlkd="1"></td>
<td id="x:1855522105.26:val:""" class="ig2d2816ff" style="width: 150px;"></td>